# Angular2 npm start failure

Tags: angular, npm-start

when i run npm start command i have this error below.  Help me please.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586

npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program

Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"

npm ERR! node v4.5.0

npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite"`

npm ERR! Exit status 2

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" '.

npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,

npm ERR! not with npm itself.

npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:

npm ERR!     tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite"

npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:

npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-quickstart

npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:

npm ERR!

npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart

npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\ugurdem'r\Desktop\angular2\npm-debug.log

Comment: what does node version and npm version say?

Comment: node version : v4.5.0
npm version : 2.15.9

Comment: You need npm 3.x.x or higher. Upgrade npm version and then try again.

Comment: i upgraded to npm but still having the same problem.
http://prntscr.com/cewf5y

Comment: are you working out of VS? if so it may not be picking up your updates to npm and still referencing the old versions

Comment: Also if your positive your project is referencing the correct versions of npm and node, then you will need to provide more info on your project. I.E your package.json and your systemjs.config.js, these are important to diagnosing this type of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the start field in package.json is

```
"start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
```

and not

```
"start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest versions of node and angular/cli,you can check the version of node using node -v,npm version using npm -v and angular/cli version using angular --version or ng -version and in package.json file change to either `start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` or `start": "lite-server`.It's better if you install angular/cli globally.